# FaceDetector error exist in btk_FaceFinder_putDCR

Tags: android

I am trying to detect a face from a camera picture.

But it always ends up in the following error:

ERROR: Return 0 faces because error exists in btk_FaceFinder_putDCR.

My code:

```
FaceDetector fd = new FaceDetector(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 1);
        Face[] faces = new Face[1];
        int nrOfFaces = fd.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);
```

The only problem I see with that code is, that I dont know the 
Bitmap Config and I dont know ho to convert a Bitmap to the Config.RGB_565 format.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I had the same problem. Try installing on phone. Worked for me on phone not emulator.

Answer (score 12):

The width of the image MUST be [even](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#FaceDetector%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching, 
You should put your images in **drawable-nodpi** folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap565 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of http://developers.android.com if the image **width** is not even then this exception occur.

For further detail check this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html

Comment: You did see @pprados 's answer?

Comment: @bummi No i just answered because recently i m working on face detection project.

Comment: @ Oleg Gordiichuk for description i add link in my answer.