# "return 0 faces because error exists btk_facefinder_putdcr" Error in Android face detector

Tags: android, image-processing, face-detection

```
fd = new FaceDetector(mFaceWidth, mFaceHeight, MAX_FACES);
count = fd.findFaces(mFaceBitmap, faces);
```

Using the above code I'm getting this error on some images.

> return 0 faces because error exists btk_facefinder_putdcr

Can someone help me? How to get rid of this?

The same code works fine for some other images.

Comment: Try to put your images in drawable-nodpi folder.
If not check this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171494/facedetector-error-exist-in-btk-facefinder-putdcr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.csdn.net/devilkin64/article/details/8509767
传入的图片的宽度必须是偶数的

```
Bitmap srcImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUrl);
    Bitmap srcFace = srcImg.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    srcImg = null;
    int w = srcFace.getWidth();
    int h = srcFace.getHeight();
    if (w % 2 == 1) {
        w++;
        srcFace = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcFace,
                srcFace.getWidth()+1, srcFace.getHeight(), false);
    }
    if (h % 2 == 1) {
        h++;
        srcFace = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcFace,
                srcFace.getWidth(), srcFace.getHeight()+1, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171494/facedetector-error-exist-in-btk-facefinder-putdcr), the image width needs to be even. I faced the same problem so I scaled the image width by one if the width was odd. And it started working :)

```
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

            background_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_fn, bitmap_options);
            if((1==(background_image.getWidth()%2))){
                background_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background_image, 
                    background_image.getWidth()+1, background_image.getHeight(), false);
            }
            FaceDetector face_detector = new FaceDetector(
                                    background_image.getWidth(), background_image.getHeight(),
                                    MAX_FACES);
            faces = new FaceDetector.Face[MAX_FACES];
            face_count = face_detector.findFaces(background_image, faces);
            Log.d("Face_Detection", "Face Count: " + String.valueOf(face_count));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when I created a new "drawable" folder to hold the image, without the "-hdpi" at the end of "drawable" it worked.  Only problem I have now is scaling the image to fit the screen but this should be relatively straight forward.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting images from gallery and camera and this error come then check the width of bitmap
where you apply facedetection it must be 1.

As per the documentation of `developers.android.com` if the image width is not even then this exception occur.
for further detail check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) link.

Or if u are not getting image from gallery and taken from camera then place the image in the folder name drawable.